# How to handle tuples in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, tuples

The code is in ExtJS. The data I am getting from a grid panel. When the user clicks on a row, i am retrieving the data to autopopulate the popup.

```
for(index = 0; index < grid_obj.getStore().getCount(); index++){
if(sm.isSelected(index)){ 
selected_row = index;
record = grid_obj.getStore().getAt(index);
record_data = record.data.field;
s_record = record_data.toString().replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');
}
}
```

I have a ExtJS code and the back end code is written in Python. I have following situation:

```
data = (1,2,4);
```

This is the format returned by the python code which i cannot modify. I need to convert it into an array so that i can access its elements using `indexOf`. I tried various approaches like:

```
record = Array(data.toString().replace('(','').replace(')','').split(','));
```

If I do `alert(record.indexOf('2'))` it gives me -1.

Comment: That's a string or what? Like `var fromPython = "data = (1,2,4);";`?

Comment: if i do typeof(data), it gives "object".

Comment: If you `console.log` it, what does the object look like in firebug/chrome?

Answer (score 1):

How is the data sent to the client? Javascript will always get it as a string, and the string representation of aa tuple looks like this: looks like this: `"(1,2,3,4)"`. To get these numbers into an array, you can do this:

```
tuple = "(1,2,3,4,5)"; // just getting some test data, you'll probably get this in an AJAX response from the server
data = tuple.substring(1,tuple.length - 1).split(",");
```

Now you have an Array of strings, each containing the data in the tuple.

If you now want to convert this to an array of integers, you can do something like this:

```
for(index in dat)
{
    data[index] = Number(data[index])

}
```

Comment: It gives tuple.substring is not a function

Comment: as what kind of type do you get the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
record = data.toString().replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');
```

Remove the extra `Array(..)` since `split(..)` returns an array itself.

Comment: That also i had tried. If i do record.indexOf('2'); it gives "-1".. It only gives the index of the last element correctly :(

Comment: What is the string you receive? Can you update the question with the **exact** string you are receing?

Comment: The extact data is : (8, 57, 7) and typeof(record) = object

Comment: You need to be more precise. How does the javascript look like? Post some code (by updating your question). Are you receiving it as a string in an AJAX call, or is it a part of HTML (If so, is it enclosed within quotes or not)?

Comment: On firebug console it looks like ["(8,57,7)"]

Comment: I tried doing ` record = data[0].replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');` which is also not working when i try "indexOf" ... it returns -1.. :(

Comment: Debug it step by step. Do a `console.log(ecord_data.toString())` first to see what is the type. If you get what you expect, move ahead. Do a `console.log(ecord_data.toString().replace('(',''))`, and so on. This will help you figure out where is the problem. And  next time, please be accurate in your description. When you say I have output XYZ, please also say what was your input ABC.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it by yourself,let's say we have tuple returned by Python like below:

```
((2, 'C/C++', 0, 'clang_cpp'), (3, 'Python相关', 0, 'python'))
```

First, we keep reading the characters in the tuple string but stores the last left semicolon's position and how many semicolons we have meet (we can call it left semicolon level, as so for right semicolons), whenever we meet a right semicolon, we do things below:

1. Take a substring from last semicolon to current right semicolon.(In
   this substring, there is no more semicolons, we just split it into
   array by ",". Let's say the new array is `M`)
2. Then we append `M` to our result array, which array will stores all`M`.
3. Thirdly, delete the substring we taken from the original string.
4. Finally, do the same things like step 1 till the right and left
           semicolon's level comes to 0.

JavaScript code is like below:

```js
function parseTuple(t){
    var lc = "(";
    var rc = ")";
    var lc_level = 0;
    var rc_level = 0;
    var last_lc = 0;
    var last_rc = 0;
    var result = [];
    for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        if(t[i] == lc){
            lc_level++;
            last_lc = i;
        }else if(t[i] == rc){
            rc_level++;
            last_rc = i;
        }
        if(rc_level == 1){
            var substr = t.slice(last_lc+1,last_rc);
            var data = substr.split(",");
            result.push(data);
            lc_level--;
            rc_level--;
            i = 0;
            t = t.slice(0,last_lc) + t.substring(last_rc+1);
        }
        if(lc_level == rc_level && lc_level==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```